# Pause Code Execution in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel

Is there a way to temporarily pause code execution (for debugging purposes) while working in the Linux kernel, like a getchar() or a system("PAUSE") type operation?

Comment: You mean pause the whole kernel? Then who's going to execute anything else (like the debugger)?

Comment: you cannot pause the kernel on some machines, for example, some laptops have their cooling system managed by the kernel - if you stop it the machine could overheat. You might want to use `kgdb` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the GNU debugger, `gdb`. Remember that you have to compile your code with `-g` flag in order to get it work.

For example:
`$ gcc -g -o out -c file.c`

Then execute your program through the debugger:
`$ gdb ./out <params>`

It worth reading the manual pages of `gdb` if you don't have any idea of the usage.
`$ man gdb`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It says "code execution...while working in the Linux kernel". As far as I know `getchar()` is not kernel function, is it? I think he did not know how to ask for the debugger.

Comment: @KiaMorot both getchar and system("PAUSE") are fairly similar windows techniques that stop userspace program execution.
If he was actually asking on how to do the same but in Linux kernel, then this answer wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's gdb remote debugging procedure:

http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_17.html

I'm not sure the linux kernel can be debugged that way.

The FreeBSD kernel probably allows this:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-online-gdb.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's technically possible to debug kernel on the fly via kgdb (and separate machine, since it typically connects via serial port).

More practical way though is to either generate kernel dump and debug that (just google it, it's fairly straight forward).

If you really need to debug running part of kernel, create yourself a worker thread and debug that (it won't lockup your system).

You can pause your worker thread via function set_current_state(TASK_STOPPED),
and to "unfreeze" it you will have to use set_task_state(task_mm_struct_pointer, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two tools that are designed for that purpose (assuming you want to debug kernel code, not userspace code) in the kernel itself. They both share the same framework so they are quite similar in how to setup them:

- `KDB` - which allows you to do limited debugging without any additional software tools. In some cases (like when you have KMS graphics driver and PS/2 keyboard) it's even possible to do this on the same machine. My fedora kernel has `KDB` support compiled in and I have a intel graphics card in my laptop so I can do:

  ```
  echo kms,kdb > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
  ```

  To enable KDB on my computer. Now if I want to start debugging session, all I have to do is to call:

  ```
  echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
  ```

  Now (almost) whole kernel will be stopped and I will be presented with `kdb` prompt. To exit `kdb` and resume normal kernel operation I would type `go`. There's ton of things you can do in `kdb` console, just type `help` to learn about them
- The other mechanism is `KGDB` which allows you In order to activate `kgdb` I would run `kgdb` command from `kdb` prompt - this would switch debugger to `kgdb` mode. to connect full fledged debugger (`gdb`) and provide it with kernel image to gain access to all the symbols in the kernel. You can active `kgdb` the same way as `kdb`, configuring its output using `kdboc` kernel parameter. In this can, however, you need serial connection to other computer which will run `kdb`. So you will use something like:

  ```
  echo ttyS0 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
  ```

  Now, if you have both `kdb` and `kgdb` enabled, the first one will be run by default. You can enter `kgdb` mode from `kdb` shell by using `kgdb` command. It's also possible to get back to `kdb` by typing `$3#33`. Now if you're in `kgdb` mode, open up `gdb` on the second computer connected using serial, giving your `vmlinux` as an argument and use something like `target remote /dev/ttyS0` to connect to the computer you want to debug.

Those are the basics, you can find more information in `Documentation/DocBook/kgdb.tmpl` in your kernel sources.